# Since XHTML documents SHOULD be served as "application/xhtml+xml", and the XML DOM document object has no "cookie", what's the alternative?

Tags: dom, cookies, xhtml-1.0-strict

Since XHTML documents SHOULD be served as "application/xhtml+xml", and the XML DOM document object has no "cookie" (among other missing features), what's the cross-platform alternative to using document.cookie?

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20020801/

> "In summary, 'application/xhtml+xml' SHOULD be used for XHTML Family
>   documents, and the use of 'text/html' SHOULD be limited to
>   HTML-compatible XHTML 1.0 documents. 'application/xml' and 'text/xml'
>   MAY also be used, but whenever appropriate, 'application/xhtml+xml'
>   SHOULD be used rather than those generic XML media types."

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), which offers `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`.

`sessionStorage` http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute 
`localStorage` http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute